# Rotate a View by 180 degrees and the View is reversed?

Tags: android, rotation

The question is about a Demo(Rotate3dAnimation) in ApiDemos bundled with the Android SDK.

I want to use this cool 3D animation effect in my app, it's easy to adapt the code to my app. Now the problem is that after being rotated by 180 degrees, the View is completely reversed, texts on the View are reversed by 180 degrees. Well I know this is expected by the code, but what I want is the rotation effect(rotating the View but not the content on the View).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: OK, I solved the problem myself. 

I only need to rotate my View by 360 degrees so the content on the View will not be reversed.

PS. I wanted to add an answer to this question but was not allowed since I didn't have enough reputation.

Comment: ok..im increasing your reputation one vote up to your question

Comment: Thanks~ 8 more to go to say thanks to you~ ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself. I only need to rotate my View by 360 degrees so the content on the View will not be reversed.